# Triggering part of validation annotations JPA/HIBERNATE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity and I'm saving it over two methods. Firstly only two fields are persisted and in the second method the rest of them are persisted. It's all fine if i don't have validation annotations. But I want it to be validated with the annotations that i have in the class shown below. Is it possible not to trigger the second part of annotations on the initial save and set some default values to not filled fields and only trigger them when I'm updating the entity?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INTERN_POSITION")
public class InternPosition {

  // first method fields
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "POSITION_UID")
  private int positionUID;

  @Column(name = "POSITION")
  @NotNull
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Position position;

  // second method fields
  @Column(name = "EXPERIENCE")
  @NotNull
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Experience experience;

  @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
  @NotBlank
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "MOTIVATION")
  @NotBlank
  private String motivation;

  ....
}
```